# Is Void an initial or zero element?

Tags: haskell, types, category-theory

[`ZeroObject`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:ZeroObject) of [Control.Category.Constrained](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html) defaults to `Void`. It is obvious that `Void` is an **initial object**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd x = case x of
```

But why is it called `ZeroObject`? On one hand, since `UnitObject` defaults to `()` and we have a very nice match with arithmetic:

```
((), x) ≅ x ≅ (x, ()); 1 * x = x = x * 1.
Void + x ≅ x ≅ x + Void; 0 + x = x = x + 0.
```

But on the other hand, the term **zero object** is used for objects that are both **initial** and **terminal**. <del>Truth be told, I can't see how `Void` is **terminal**. Unlike `absurd` which helps us run the error which claims to be of `Void` type, I reckon `a -> Void` not to do anything useful as the argument is not guaranteed to hold an error, therefore making us throw the same exception every time.</del> <sub>See HTNW's comment.</sub>

<del>Am I right about `Void` not being a terminal object?</del> Do we use `Void`'s **terminal** feature or was the name `ZeroObject` chosen to match arithmetic?

Comment: Side note: ``giveUp :: a -> Void; giveUp x = x `seq` error "giving up"`` does in fact try to get the exception out of its argument before throwing its own (well, it's technically not defined which exception you'll get, but GHC will usually look for one in `x` first.)

Comment: @HTNW you are right - didn't think of that. I will add it to the post. I guess, it even makes it **terminal**. But are we using this feature?

Comment: In the orthodox (fast-and-loose) way of thinking about Haskell as a category, `()` is terminal, not `Void`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I know, that is why I mentioned `UnitObject` which defaults to `()`. But what stops us from having more than one terminal objects? I believe, `id :: a -> a` has the same property, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor In any category, all terminal objects are isomorphic to each other. Certainly `()` and `Void` are not isomorphic, whether you support fast and loose reasoning or demand not to use it. Proof that all terminal objects are isomorphic follows. Suppose X and Y are terminal. Because X is terminal, there exists a unique arrow a : Y -> X. Because Y is terminal, there exists a unique arrow b : X -> Y. And a and b are inverses of each other: since X is terminal, there is a unique arrow id = a . b : X -> X, and similarly for Y and b . a.

Comment: @DanielWagner all **terminal objects** being isomorphic to each other is pretty much obvious. I guess we just cannot have **terminal objects** and bottoms in our category at the same time.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor "We cannot have terminal objects and bottoms in our category at the same time" is not at all clear to me. Presumably whether you think about Haskell as having bottoms or not just gives you two different categories, and of course the terminal objects in different categories are not the same.

Comment: @DanielWagner I guess I am a bit lost. If we take **Hask** with bottoms, what would be the **terminal object(s)**? I have heard that **Hask** is not formalised fully, but I am not sure to which extent. I guess leaving bottoms would be fine, but what would happen if we start differentiating the exception based on what information they contain (that is treating `error "ERROR!!"` and `undefined` as different values)? Or does such approach make no sense?

Comment: Take all of this with a grain of salt, because we haven't carefully defined any categories yet. But: in the category where we admit that bottoms exist, if it has a terminal object, I would be shocked to learn that terminal object was not `Void`. In the category where we admit that exceptions are different from each other, I would be shocked to learn that there was a terminal object at all.

Comment: Haskell with all its bottoms *and `seq`* isn't a category because it has no identity arrows. ``(id . undefined) `seq` () = ()`` while ``undefined `seq` () = undefined``.

Comment: @dfeuer Just use strict composition (```f .# g = f `seq` g `seq` \x -> f (g x)```) as the category's composition and that objection is neutralized.

Comment: @DanielWagner "In the category where we admit that exceptions are different from each other, I would be shocked to learn that there was a terminal object at all", - I guess that is what I was trying to say. Sorry for bad wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although "zero object" is, indeed, sometimes used for objects that are both initial and terminal, it is also the case, in grand mathematical tradition, that it is sometimes used in a different and conflicting way!

Specifically, when talking about coproducts, it is very common to use the notation 0 to refer to an initial object (which is then the identity for the coproduct). See for example [the Wikipedia page on coproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) ("0 denotes the initial object" in the discussion of "all finite coproducts"). This is the sense in which "ZeroObject" is being used here: initial, and more importantly, the identity for the coproduct.

(By the way, it is possible that category theoreticians chose the notation 0 as the identity for coproducts because of the analogy to arithmetic; but the reason this library uses the term ZeroObject is because CT uses 0 for identity, not because arithmetic does. The fact that CT uses this because of arithmetic is one step of indirection away from the reason, in other words.)

Comment: It is also nice to have types having a given finite number of (total) values. Zero `Void`, one `()`, and two `Bool` are sometimes written as `0`, `1`, and `2` in theoretical papers since it's a very natural notation.

Comment: @chi well, I guess that is how the isomorphisms `((), x) ≅ x ≅ (x, ()); Void + x ≅ x ≅ x + Void; Bool ≅ () + ()` work.